# pymongo - querying most recent N items

Tags: python, pymongo

What is the 'proper way' to retrieve most recent N items from the database?

from tutorial and mongodb documentations it seems (besides using range queries)

`db.collection.find(skip = 0, limit=N, sort=[("_id", -1)])`

is it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax doesn't really seem quite right there.

```
db.collection.find({}).sort("_id", -1).limit(N)
```

Should do what you would expect.

Python and pymongo support simple chaining.

---

**NOTE**
Sorting on `_id` does not necessarily yield the "most recent" item.

Comment: I run exactly this command on a collection and get the following error:
`  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 513, in sort
    keys = helpers._index_list(key_or_list, direction)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 47, in _index_list
    raise TypeError("if no direction is specified, "
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list`

Comment: When you say "exactly" did you change the collection name to your collection's name?

Comment: Yes. =)  Sorry, maybe I read this too quickly, but this did work fine in the mongo terminal, just not when I tried it in pymongo.  I was looking quickly at the tags, and assumed this was intended as raw python syntax with pymongo.

Comment: I found that you can't do `.sort({"_id": -1})` and instead this worked using `.sort("_id", -1)`